# Ext JS: createStyleSheet problems with two classes

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, stylesheet

```
Ext.util.CSS.createStyleSheet(
  '.cleanForm .x-form-text.x-superboxselect { background: none; border-color: white; } ' +
  '.cleanForm .mySuperSelectItem a { background: url(../sprite.png) no-repeat 0px -50px; } ' +      
  Ext.id( null, 'someStyleSheet')
);
```

This stylesheet works in FireFox.  The second rule works in IE.  The first rule does not work in IE.  It appears when IE loads the stylesheet, it ignores the third class creating a rule not applicable for my code.

Has anybody seen problems with multiple class selectors that follow a third, parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of IE are you using? I tested IE9 on [this mulitclass selector test page](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/multiclass.html) and it doesn't look like it properly supports multiclass selectors in quirks mode. Have you set a doctype? Switching to standards mode in IE7+ looks better.

Some cursory googling found [this blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/680-Defining-A-CSS-Selector-That-Requires-A-Multi-Class-Union.htm) with a good discussion in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I looked at your page and it works fine for me in IE.  In my original question, I failed to include a third class I actually use in my css - see the modified code above.  Maybe this third class is causing the problem?

Comment: Open the IE developer tools with F12 and check the document mode in the toolbar. Is your page rendering in standards mode? If you check the demo page I linked in quirks mode, it doesn't render the multiclass elements correctly.